# How do I call an contentOffset from another view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentoffset

```
class oneViewController: UIViewController{
   let sv = UIScrollView();
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad();

   sv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, screenWidth, screenHeight);
   sv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
   sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: sv.frame.size.width*3 ,height: sv.frame.size.height);
   sv.delegate = self;
   scrollToContentOffsetX(screenWidth);
   self.view.addSubview(sv);
   }


  func scrollToContentOffsetX(offsetX:CGFloat) {

       sv.contentOffset.x = offsetX;
  }
}
```

I can scroll UIScrollView,it working.But I call from another View,its not working.

```
class anthorView: UIView{

    override init (frame : CGRect)
    {

    super.init(frame : frame)

      let btnForget = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth-155, txtPWD.frame.origin.y+txtPWD.frame.size.height+5, 70, 30));
      btnForget.setTitle("Forget", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
      btnForget.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
      btnForget.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnForget_Click), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside);
      btnForget.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14);
      btnForget.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
      self.addSubview(btnForget);
    }

func btnForget_Click(sender: AnyObject) {

    oneViewController().scrollToContentOffsetX(0);

  }
}
```

I have breakpoint,both have go func scrollToContentOffsetX(offsetX:CGFloat).
who can help me and sry for my English

Comment: What is `LogInViewController`? Did you realize that you create a new instance of it?

Comment: my typo,i fixed it,thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in your code pointed by @AminNegm-Awad: in `btnForget_Click` you create completely new instance of `oneViewController`, which will never appear on screen and have no connection to existed `oneViewController`. You need to have pointer to your existed instance of `oneViewController` in your `anthorView` instance. Usual way for view to "talk" with controller is protocol-delegate. Read about it by yourself; here I will offer another solution with closure. Anyway, you will need to have pointer to your `anthorView` instance (lets declare it as `anthorViewInstance` property) in `oneViewController`. Here is changes that you need add to your classes

**class anthorView:**

```
var offsetClosure: (CGFloat -> ())?

func btnForget_Click(sender: AnyObject) {
    // delete previous implementation
    offsetClosure?(0)
}
```

**class oneViewController:**

```
var anthorViewInstance: anthorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // some your code...

    // next line is initialization of anthorView, do it in other place if you wish
    anthorViewInstance = anthorView(frame: CGRectZero)
    anthorViewInstance.offsetClosure = 
        {
             [weak self]
             offsetX in
             self?.scrollToContentOffsetX(offsetX)
        }    
}
```

---

Also, there is local case for this solution can be performed in your case. You may set button action of `anthorView` directly from view controller. For do this declare button as property in `anthorView`

**class anthorView:**

```
var btnForget: UIButton!

super.init(frame : frame) {
    btnForget = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth-155, txtPWD.frame.origin.y+txtPWD.frame.size.height+5, 70, 30))

    // ... other init code

    // remove btnForget.addTarget line
}

// move btnForget_Click method to view controller
```

**class oneViewController:**

```
var anthorViewInstance: anthorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // some your code...

    // next line is initialization of anthorView, do it in other place if you wish
    anthorViewInstance = anthorView(frame: CGRectZero)
    anthorViewInstance.btnForget.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnForget_Click), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)  
}

func btnForget_Click() {
    scrollToContentOffsetX(0)
}
```